# Is this possible to create one custom user property in SharePoint Online for all the users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile-property, azure-ad

In SharePoint Online, one of my clients wants to have one custom property for all the users' data which needs to be displayed in one custom screen later. 
Is this possible to have one custom property in SharePoint online.? I am actually not clear about the custom property usage in SharePoint Online. Because few places, it was written like "Custom properties from Active Directory or Azure AD are not synchronized with SharePoint". If it is really possible, do I need to create in Azure AD and how? Could you share any helpful links to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Online, you can create custom user profile properties. If we create the properties in user profile it will be the personalized values for the users. As these custom new properties doesn't have any relationship to the Active Directory or Azure AD, so we cannot sync it.

In order to create it, you should have the following,

1. You are using SharePoint online (Office 365) environment
2. You have admin access on your tenant

Follow the below steps,

Step 1: Go to SharePoint online admin center.

Step 2: Click on “User Profiles” from the left navigation.

Step 3: On user profile settings page, select Manage User Properties

Step 4: Click “New Property” to create new property,

Step 5: On the new property page, you can add the property details

Step 6: map the property to term set also, but you need to check the “configure Term set to be used for this property”,
From the dropdown, you can choose the term set.

Step 7: Provide all mandatory fields and settings as you need them. After that click OK to create a property,

For more information, refer the below links,

[Create Custom User Profile Property In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/93cb27/create-custom-user-profile-property-in-sharepoint-online/)

[How to Create Custom User Profile Property in SharePoint Online](https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000277712-how-to-create-custom-user-profile-property-in-sharepoint-online)

[Add and edit user profile properties in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/add-and-edit-user-profile-properties)

Once after creating the custom user profile property in SharePoint, then if you want to update it with the custom AD property value, then refer the steps mentioned in the below link,

[Sync Custom Active Directory Attributes with SharePoint Online User Profiles](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/sync-custom-active-directory-attributes-with-sharepoint-online/m-p/30663)

[Introducing Bulk UPA Custom Profile Properties Update API for SharePoint Online](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/introducing-bulk-upa-custom-profile-properties-update-api/)

Comment: Thank you Karthick for your quick response.

The issue that I am facing is:

The client has a custom AD property that they want to sync with SharePoint Online.
I am able to sync default user profile properties but not this custom one.
Is it possible to sync this custom AD property with SharePoint online user profile.

Comment: updated my answer, kindly check.

Comment: if you find my answer useful, kindly upvote and accept it as answer, so that it will help others too.